# Sreality.cz web scraping

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rvest

I have tried scraping data from a real estate site, and arranging the data in a way that can then easily be filtered and checked using a spreadsheet. I’m actually a little embarrassed that i don’t move of this R code forward. 
Now that i have all the links to the posts, i can not now loop through the previously compiled dataframe and get the details from all the URLs.

Could you just please help me with it? Thanks a lot.

```r
#Loading the rvest package
library(rvest)
library(magrittr) # for the '%>%' pipe symbols
library(RSelenium) # to get the loaded html of
library(xml2)

complete <- data.frame()

# starting local RSelenium (this is the only way to start RSelenium that is working for me atm)
selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()  

URL.base <- "https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty?strana="

  #"https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/praha?strana="

  #"https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/praha?stari=dnes&strana="

  #"https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/praha?stari=tyden&strana="

for (i in 1:10000) {

    #Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
    main_link<- paste0(URL.base, i)

    # go to website
    remDr$navigate(main_link)

    # get page source and save it as an html object with rvest
    main_page <- remDr$getPageSource(header = TRUE)[[1]] %>% read_html()

    # get the data
    name <-  html_nodes(main_page, css=".name.ng-binding") %>% html_text()
    locality <- html_nodes(main_page, css=".locality.ng-binding") %>% html_text()
    norm_price <- html_nodes(main_page, css=".norm-price.ng-binding") %>% html_text()
    sreality_url <- main_page %>% html_nodes(".title") %>% html_attr("href")

    sreality_url2 <- sreality_url[c(4:24)]
    name2 <- name[c(4:24)]

    record <- data.frame(cbind(name2, locality, norm_price, sreality_url2))

    complete <- rbind(complete, record)
}

# Write CSV in R
write.csv(complete, file = "MyData.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this differently:
I would  create a function, say 'scraper', that groups up together all the scraping functions you have already defined, doing so I'll create a list with the str_c of all the possibile links (say 30), after that a simple lapply function. As it all said, I will not use Rselenium. (libraries: rvest , stringr , tibble, dplyr )

```
url = 'https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty?strana='
```

here it is the URL base, starting from here you should be able to replicate the URL strings for all the pages (1 to whichever) you are interested in (and for all the possible url, for praha, olomuc, ostrava etc ).

```
 main_page = read_html('https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty?strana=')
```

here you create all the linnks according to the number of pages you want:

```
list.of.pages = str_c(url, 1:30)
```

then define a single function for all the single data you are interested, in this way you are more precise and your error debug is easier, as well as the data quality. (I assume your CSS selections are right, otherwise you will obtain empty obj)

for names

```
name = function(url) {

data = html_nodes(url, css=".name.ng-binding") %>% 
html_text()
return(data)
}
```

for locality

```
locality = function(url) {

data = html_nodes(url, css=".locality.ng-binding") %>% 
html_text()
return(data)
}
```

for normprice

```
normprice = function(url) {

data = html_nodes(url, css=".norm-price.ng-binding") %>% 
html_text()
return(data)
}
```

for hrefs

```
sreality_url = function(url) {

data = html_nodes(url, css=".title") %>% 
html_attr("href")
return(data)
}
```

those are the single fuctions (the CSS selection, even if i didnt test them, seem to be not correct to me, but this will give you the right framework to work on). After that combine them into a tibble obj

```
 get.data.table = function(html){
  name = name(html)
  locality = locality(html)
  normprice = normprice(html)
  hrefs = sreality_url(html)

  combine = tibble(adtext  = name,
                   loc     = locality, 
                   price   = normprice,
                   URL     = sreality_url)
  combine %>%
    select(adtext, loc, price, URL)   return(combine)
}
```

then the final scraper:

```
scrape.all = function(urls){
  list.of.pages %>% 
    lapply(get.data.table) %>%  
    bind_rows() %>%
    write.csv(file = 'MyData.csv')
}
```